# A way to return DOM objects or jQuery within Slickgrid's column formatters

Tags: dom, slickgrid, formatter

Slickgrid's column formatters return html to the grid object, so basically there's no way to attach events on elements created within the formatters. One has to use $.live() to capture those elements, why does Slickgrid formatter use HTML and not DOM objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Because it's faster to render it this way.
2)  To discourage developers from doing what you are trying to do :)  This approach is not scalable.  Using event delegation is the way to go here.

Comment: After messing with SlickGrid fantastic API, I realized injecting HTML would be much speedier than creating objects. I ended up writing a column plugin for my button strip and used event delegation like you mentioned, works like a charm :)